# What is Ubuntu Soyuz?

Tags: launchpad

When I was building an application in Launchpad, I found that in Karma, there is Ubuntu Soyuz. It found that it also increase my Karma,

Can any one tell me what is meaning of Ubuntu  Soyuz?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Soyuz is Launchpad's ["archive management infrastructure"](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-announce/2006-February/000072.html). You use it to compile packages for PPAs, but it's also used for *all* the regular packages that go into the Ubuntu releases and the official repositories.

Briefly, the process [as described by one of Soyuz's lead maintainers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MeetingLogs/devweek0909/HackSoyuz) is:

> 1. It starts with the 'upload server', an FTP daemon that receives source packages uploaded by users using `dput/dupload`.
> 2. Sources are them passed to the 'upload processor' which verifies their consistency (packaging metadata) and stores its information in the Launchpad database.
> 3. the publication of the source automatically creates a build request, which is dealt by the 'build dispatching' component.
> 4. it passes the source to a 'builder', an isolated environment for running `debuild`.
> 5. Binaries resulted from the build process come back to the upload processor and are checked before getting stored in Launchpad.

Here's a *very*-comprehensive [flowchart of Soyuz](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CelsoProvidelo/SoyuzInfrastructureOverview):

[image]